# Database level trigger in Oracle db

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I would like to track whoever trying to login to the db using a trigger. I would like to have suggestions over this. We are using multiple dbs and people are locking it , we have to reasonable way to find who did this. So we decided to track whoever tries to login to the db, no matter if it is successful or not.. And I'm hardly having an idea on where to begin from. And other possible way to avoid this issue will also be welcomed..

Comment: Justin's answer is correct. A trigger can only fire after a *successful* login.

Answer (score 0):

You want to [audit failed login attempts](http://www.oracle-wiki.net/startdocshowtoauditafailedlogonattempt) rather than creating a trigger.

Recent versions of Oracle have enabled auditing of failed login attempts out of the box.  So there is every chance that you already have the information you're looking for in `dba_audit_trail`.